# deleting Leaflet realtime markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map that tracks realtime data and i currently have it updating the positions correctly every x seconds, but the old markers are not being deleted. Im at the point that I will just remove all markers and re-add them. I think this is also impacting memory for the page, because the values increase by 166 every time

I have to be overlooking something really silly.

My json is like:

```
{"_items": [{"uniqueID": "a123", "isMoving": false, "bearing": 231, "longitude": -xx.xxxxx, "latitude": xx.xxxxx}]}
```

And here is the code that adds the markers

```
var marker = new Array();
for(i=0;i<myjson._items.length;i++){
    var LamMarker = new L.marker([myjson._items[i].latitude, myjson._items[i].longitude],{
       icon: autotop
    });
    console.log(myjson._items[i].latitude)
    marker.push(LamMarker);
    map.addLayer(marker[i]);
    }
}
```

i have been trying something along the lines of

```
if (map.hasLayer(marker)) {
  for(i=0;i<marker.length;i++) {
map.removeLayer(marker[i])
   }
  }
```

before my function fires.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I would use the uniqueID to check if you've added it: storing it like { 123: L.marker }.  To remove old ones, maybe keep an array of all new ids and remove any markers with ids that aren't in that array?

Comment: Side note: make sure you understand [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Right now, i'm just looking to remove all of the markers, then re add them when the new data comes in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extremely simple way of deleting all your markers is to use an intermediary [Layer Group](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#layergroup): instead of adding your Markers directly to your map, add the group to the map, and your Markers into the group. Then remove all its child Markers with its [`clearLayers()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#layergroup-clearlayers) method:

> Removes all the layers from the group.

```js
var map = L.map("map").setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

function refreshMarkers() {
  layerGroup.clearLayers();
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    L.marker(getRandomLatLng()).addTo(layerGroup);
  }
}

setInterval(refreshMarkers, 2000);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

function getRandomLatLng() {
  return [
    48.8 + 0.1 * Math.random(),
    2.25 + 0.2 * Math.random()
  ];
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and i also reviewed the link you posted and rewrote the async call. I'm fairly new to js so i'm sure there are better ways to do some of the things i'm trying, but regardless thank you