# How to remove a layer in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, marker

I am working on circleMarker on leaflet. A method which has latLng will be refreshed for each 5 seconds and new latLng will be returned. So when a method is loaded I need to remove previous layer and should show new points(layer) on a map.

Here is sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/GZHJX/121/

I used `.removeLayer()`, but it's not working. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're using a [very old version of Leaflet (0.4)](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#04-2012-07-30). Switch to a recent version and use [`layer.remove`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#marker-remove)

An [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/GZHJX/125/) immediately removing the marker :

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

var createCircleMarker = function (latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
        icon: L.divIcon({
            className: 'circle',
            iconSize: [8, 8]
        }),
        title: 'test'
    })
}

var l = createCircleMarker([51.505, -0.09]).addTo(map);
l.remove();
```

Comment: I want to remove all previous marker.then new marker should be appended is there any way for that?please give me some ideas.

Comment: @laz see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498385/deleting-leaflet-realtime-markers/49513026#49513026