# Leaflet Update Single Marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have a `Leaflet` `OpenStreetMap` map where I set a new marker.  I want the marker to *move*, which would mean clearing all previous markers, and adding a new one.  Currently new clicks just result in new markers, with more than one staying on the map.

How can I clear all markers upon clicking again?

```
initmap();
var home = new L.LayerGroup();

map.on('click', function(e) {
  // clear all markers here somehow
  document.getElementById("latFld").value = e.latlng.lat;
  document.getElementById("lngFld").value = e.latlng.lng;
  L.marker([e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng]).addTo(map);
  });
```

Edit:

My original markers did not belong to a group.

```
L.marker([43.653409, -79.384112]).bindPopup('Original Home').addTo(map);
```

Regardless of the `LayerGroup` into a variable, I was asking if there was a way to clear all markers regardless.  It is not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deleting Leaflet realtime markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498385/deleting-leaflet-realtime-markers)

Answer (score 1):

Shoved my markers into a `layerGroup` so I can use that for clearing:

```
var mymarkers = L.layerGroup([
    L.marker([43.677681,-79.389943]).bindPopup('Some place'),
    L.marker([<%= @mylat %>,<%= @mylon %>]).bindPopup('Original Home')
]);

L.control.layers(mymarkers).addTo(mymap);

mymap.on('click', function(e) {
    mymarkers.clearLayers();
    document.getElementById("latFld").value = e.latlng.lat;
    document.getElementById("lngFld").value = e.latlng.lng;
    L.marker([e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng]).bindPopup('New ome').addTo(mymarkers);
    $('#update').html("Values updated");
});
```

I was expecting an object that automatically held all markers, but it wasn't there.  So I had to assign then to one.